# Drupal keep reinstalling after changing docker-compose.yml file

Tags: docker, dpl

Why Drupal is going so mad if you change something from docker-compose.yml file ?

Here is my docker-compose.yml file maybe something`s wrong inside

```
web:
  image: drupal:latest
  environment:
    DINAMO_DEPLOY_URL: http://some-thing
    ELASTIC_ENDPOINT: http://elastic:9200
    DRUPAL_PROFILE: standard
    DRUPAL_SITE_NAME: Drupal
    DRUPAL_USER: admin
    DRUPAL_PASS: admin
    DRUPAL_DBURL: mysql://drupal:drupal@database:3306/drupal
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
    - /var/www/html/d8/sites:/var/www/html/sites
    - /var/www/html/d8/modules:/var/www/html/modules
    - /var/www/html/d8/libraries:/var/www/html/libraries
  links:
    - database:database
    - elastic:elastic
  restart: always

database:
  image: mariadb:10
  environment:
    MYSQL_USER: drupal
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: drupal
    MYSQL_DATABASE: drupal
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ''
    MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  restart: always

elastic:
  image: elasticsearch:7.4.2
  ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
  volumes:
    - data01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
  ports:
    - 9200:9200
  environment:
    - discovery.type=single-node
    - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
  restart: always
```

The issue is for example if I change DRUPAL_SITE_NAME from Drupal to D8 or if I add new volume like

 
- /var/www/html/d8/test:/var/www/html/test

Comment: What's the actual error you're getting?

Comment: I fixed up, there were some permissions problems